# How to retrieve the edit text value from list view to another activity?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, custom-lists

In my application I have a list view with edit text ,when I enter different values in edit text in each list item and when i pass the value to next activity on button click the list item values are shown correctly but edit text value is not correct its shows only the last value for all the edit text please  help me to fix it here is my code.

my button on clcik code is here

```
order.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   /* SparseBooleanArray checked = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                        if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
                            int pos = checked.keyAt(i);
                            Object o = lv.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
                            Log.e("checked",""+checked);
                        }
                    }*/
                    StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
                    System.out.println(".............." + adapter.mCheckStates.size());
                    for (int i = 0; i < tabletlist.size(); i++)

                    {
                        if (adapter.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {


                            checkedcontacts.append(tabletlist.get(i).get(TAG_TABLET).toString());
                            checkedcontacts.append("   ");
                         // checkedcontacts.append(tabletlist.get(i).get(TAG_CONTAINS).toString());
                            checkedcontacts.append(edit);
                            Log.e("editcheck",""+edit);

                            checkedcontacts.append("\n");
                            String builderstring = checkedcontacts.toString().replace("{", "").replace("}", "");

                            Log.e("checkbuild", "" + mCheckStates);
                           // Toast.makeText(TabletList.this, checkedcontacts, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e("checkvalue", "" + checkedcontacts);


                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            //Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
                            bundle.putString("VENUE_NAME", builderstring);
                            //Add the bundle to the intent
                            Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OrderConform.class);
                            j.putExtras(bundle);
                            startActivity(j);

                        } else {
                            System.out.println("..Not Checked......" + tabletlist.get(i).toString());
                        }

                    }

                }


            });


Here is my Base adapter code  



  class TabletAdapter extends BaseAdapter

                {
                    SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
                    CheckBox cb;
                    Context context;
                    LayoutInflater inflater;
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
                    HashMap<String, String> display = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    String Tablet;
                    String Contains;
                    String Cost;
                    String Manufacture;
                     String Unit;
                    {
                        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(tabletlist.size());
                        inflater = (LayoutInflater)TabletList.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    }

                    private HashMap<String, String> textValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    public TabletAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
                        this.context = context;
                        data = arraylist;


                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getCount() {
                        return data.size();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Object getItem(int position) {
                        return position;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public long getItemId(int position) {
                        return position;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        TextView tablet;
                        TextView manufacture;
                        TextView contain;
                        TextView cost;
                        final EditText unitnum;
                        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                      //  boolean convertViewWasNull = false;

                         View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent, false);


                        display = data.get(position);

                        unitnum=(EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.unit);
                        unitnum.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

                        tablet = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Tabletname);
                        manufacture = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Manufacture);
                        contain = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Contains);
                        cost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Cost);


                        tablet.setText(display.get(TabletList.TAG_TABLET));
                        manufacture.setText(display.get(TabletList.TAG_MANUFACTURE));
                        contain.setText(display.get(TabletList.TAG_CONTAINS));
                        cost.setText(display.get(TabletList.TAG_COST));
                        cb = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                        cb.setTag(position);
                        cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
                        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                if (isChecked) {
                                    //if it is check
                                    unitnum.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                } else {
                                    unitnum.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                                mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
                            }
                        });

                        unitnum.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                                edit=unitnum.getText().toString();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            }
                        });
                        return itemView;

                    }


                    public boolean isChecked(int position) {
                        return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
                    }

                    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
                        mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
                        System.out.println("hello...........");
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    public void toggle(int position) {
                        setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
                    }
                  /*  @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                 boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                    }*/

                }
```

Comment: Where is your button click code?

Comment: @NaviRamyle How to use the View holder any example  please ??

Comment: @ganesang Try this tutorial https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: all you need to do is add an extra item in your array (unitnum) and when you set the editext with some text, update the array item (unitnum) for its position in the array with the editext. That way it gets stored. Then all you have to is grab all those (unitnum) from the array and send them to the other activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use holder for this,

```
class ViewHolder {

//Your all textview,button,edittext etc declare here like.
//TextView tvMessage;
//EditText etName;
}
```

and in getView() create holder object and access field.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    hView = convertView;
    holder = (ViewHolder) hView.getTag();
    holder.tvMessage = (TextView) hView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_message_chat_item);
    holder.etName= (EditTExt) hView
                    .findViewById(R.id.et_Name);
    holder.tvMessage.setText("Hi");
    add in your list = holder.etName.getText();//and pass this list in next activity.
}
```

Comment: Ganpat Kaliya when i use the view holder the app get crashed it doesn't work please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to update set Edit text value  after giving some delay using timer

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            //set edit text value here
                    }
                });               
        }
    }, 100);
```